# What does sapply do for given function

Tags: r

I am still learning R. Kindly, I'd like to understand this function:

```
sapply(M[,-1], function(x) x^2)
```

Where M is a matrix. It looks like it is squaring every element in M. Can someone provide a brief example of how this line functions?

Thank you

Comment: It's squaring every element in `M`, except for the first column `-1`. It's also mostly pointless because you could just do `M[,-1]^2` instead and not bother with `sapply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apply` functions family in R are of different types depending on the use case.

1.When you want apply a function to the rows or columns of a matrix , `apply()` function is used.

2. When you want to apply a function to each element of a list in turn and get a list back , we use `lapply()` function.
3. When you want to apply a function to each element of a list in turn, but you want a vector in return, and not a list - we use `sapply()` function.

In your case above yes it squares all values and returns a vector , except the first column of the matrix, see below :

```
M <- matrix(seq(10,25), 4, 4) # random 4 by 4 matrix 

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   10   14   18   22
[2,]   11   15   19   23
[3,]   12   16   20   24
[4,]   13   17   21   25

M[,-1]

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   14   18   22
[2,]   15   19   23
[3,]   16   20   24
[4,]   17   21   25


sapply(M[,-1], function(x) x^2) 

[1] 196 225 256 289 324 361 400 441 484 529 576 625
```

Comment: The third one is not 100% true.  `sapply()` will return a list **or** a vector, depending on its input (e.g. uneven length list elements).